# Osmdroid 5.6 offline tiles not load

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, offline, osmdroid

I use osmodroid map in 5.6.5 version and I want to load offline tiles from MOBAC's osmdroid zip. 
I create zip file and put it in `sdcard/osmdroid/Mapnik.zip`. 
I try to load offline tiles but it doesnt work and the map is empty. Do something wrong with my code?

```
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
    listener = new MyLocationListener(this, mapController, mMapView);
    mMapView.setUseDataConnection(false);

    mMapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("Mapnik", 2, 15, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {}));

    GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(50, 50);
    mapController.setCenter(gPt);

    OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    mapController.setZoom(15);
```

In my AndriodManifest.xml I have these permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to use that zip file?

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: In osmdroid this line find automaticaly file Mapnik.zip mMapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("Mapnik", 2, 15, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {})). I use android 6.0 but this code work well on older version like android 5.1

Comment: Are you requesting the read external storage permission also at runtime? This has to be done extra for version 6.

Comment: Yes, i ask for these permissions and they are granted Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: You are asking for permissions in your manifest file. I allready saw that! I can read! Now do you? Reread my comment please.

Comment: This is my MainActivity code: https://pastebin.com/MPVaeELe